# How to add a widget to the bottom of a reversed AnimatedList

Tags: flutter, flutter-animatedlist

I have a list of `ChatMessageEntity` and I use it in my `AnimatedList` to enable me to add another `ChatMessageEntity` to it. without rebuilding the whole list. This `AnimatedList` is reversed to show latest message first. I needed to add the `ChatMessageEntity` at the bottom. However, when I try to add the `ChatMessageEntity`, it awlays adds it at the top. I get the length of the list and use a global key of my animated list and use `listkey.currentState?.insertItem(messages.length-1);`. I don't know if this `messages.length-1` is right but when I used messages.length it gave an error that the provided index is not in the range. Can someone show me what is wrong with my code? I even changed the index to any number like 10 and it still added it to the top.

**EDIT**

```
List<ChatMessageEntity> messages = [
    // my messages
];

final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
final GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> _listKey = GlobalKey<AnimatedListState>();
    
 AnimatedList(
  initialItemCount: messages.length,
  controller: _scrollController,
  key: _listKey,
  reverse: true,
....
```

My Send Button:

```
onPressed: () {
  addMessage(ChatMessageEntity(
      id: '${messages.length + 1}',
      message: messageController.text,
      url: null,
      sender: '${UserData.firstName} ${UserData.lastName}',
      type: 'text',
      date: '${DateTime.now().hour} ${DateTime.now().minute}'));
  hasText.value = false;
  messageController.clear();
},
.....
void addMessage(ChatMessageEntity newMessage) {
  messages.add(newMessage);
  print(messages.length);
  listkey.currentState?.insertItem(10);
  scrollController.animateTo(
    0,
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    curve: Curves.easeOut,
  );
}
```

Comment: Please add your code, which you are running

Comment: I editted my question @PriyanshuPaliwal

Comment: the problem was that I was adding newMessage without specifying its index, when I replaced .add() with .insert() , it worked but I found that I have to rebuild the AnimatedList to view the change @PriyanshuPaliwal

Comment: Happy to know that you solved it.

Comment: It is not really solved yet because the AnimatedList doesn't get updated. The problem is that I am using AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin in each message so when the AnimatedList adds the message, AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin interfers with the AnimatedList. I just need to add a message without rebuilding other messages, is it possible? @PriyanshuPaliwal